# i want to make a class in python then use the class in another python file in python

Tags: python, file, class

hi i want to make a class in python then import the class in another python file in python
we have a file called `squaretypes` that has a class called `Square` then its imported in `class2` but when i want to import the python file and then use `Square` but it gives an error

note: i am using jupyter notebook

error:

> ```
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [19], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 from squaretypes import Square
>      3 newClass = Square(5)
>       4 val = newClass.getVal()
>    
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Square' from 'squaretypes' (C:\Users\DAVID\anaconda3\lib\types.py)
> ```

squaretypes:

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def getVal(self):
        return self.val * self.val
```

class2:

```
from squaretypes import Square
 
newClass = Square(5)
val = newClass.getVal()
 
print(val)
```

note: `class2` is giving a error and i am using jupyter notebook

Comment: We can see from the error message that python is importing the built-in [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) package, not your custom `types` module.  Assuming `types.py` is in the same directory as your main script, try `from .types import Square`.

Comment: Change your  "types.py" to some other name. Try to avoid name clashes with builtin, standard lib and other popular module and package names.

Comment: @0x5453 - top level scripts are not part of packages and so package relative imports have no package to be relative to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to do following things

**- You can rename the name of classes**

- **if the above technic doesn't work just create an object without main in global and import it in the second python file . it will be imported with the values and functions, but you have to do some change in functions as well**

Answer (score 4):

"types" is the name of a standard library in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html
Rename your file to something different, e.g. "squaretype.py".